# Significance to an unveiling

Tags: death, mourning-aveilus, cemetery-grave

What is the religious significance to an unveiling of the deceased's stone? (Assuming there is)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you talking about the grave stone? Maybe you could elaborate more. What is this "unveiling ceremony" of the gravestone you talk about? Please [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/86676/edit) to clarify. It's not a bad question, we just need more info.

Comment: Why assume there is? Is it some traditional part? Do you disagree with the Rishonim that there is such a thing as minhag shtut. Can't it just be a comforting closure ceremony?

Comment: Highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46203/8775 about the origin of the practice. Note that according to the answers there it is not a traditional Jewish practice, and may be non Jewish in origin.